# set duration playing with exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a service player, which is working well.
I have list audio sounds, which I want to play sequentially during the different minute times.

My code :

```
 val sourceList = mutableListOf<ExtractorMediaSource>()
    listSounds.forEach {
       val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(it)
       val source = ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null)
       sourceList.add(source)
    }
mPlayer!!.prepare(ConcatenatingMediaSource(*sourceList.toTypedArray()))
```

I want to repeat the source list for 10 or 20 minutes. How can I set the duration ?

Comment: Did you found any solution?